# Place Text in Image on Edges

Tags: vb.net, image, visual-studio-2010, composition, aspect-ratio

[image]
This tool I wrote in Visual Basic 2010 should add an author text to images. The user is able to set the font opacity and position. To make things easier I wanted some position presets as one can see in the bottom right corner. The calculation I am using is (bottom right in this case:

```
 Dim textSize As Size = TextRenderer.MeasureText(tagString + curText, curFont)
 tmpPos = New Point(srcImg.Width - textSize.Width - 10, srcImg.Height - textSize.Height - 10)
```

As you can see this works perfectly for this example picture. Where as on some the text just clips out.
[image]

First One: 1024x768 | Detected Font Size: 680x72

Second One: 1688x1125 | Detected Font Size: 680x72

I suspect this has something to do with the aspect ratio of the images but I do not know how to fix it.

The text is drawn like that:

```
 brush = New SolidBrush(color.FromArgb(alpha, color))
        gr = Graphics.FromImage(editImg)
        gr.DrawString(tagString + text, font, brush, pos)
        HauptBild.Image = editImg
```

I found this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20923/Mouse-Position-over-Image-in-a-PictureBox and it answered my questions.

Comment: can you include the code that places the text please?

Comment: pls add some code, can you just put the code that modify the image?

Comment: Some codes will really be helpful

Comment: Sorry guys I have been busy the last few days. The sizemode is zoom because I want to fit any size of image into the imagebox. I will edit mit post and add some code

Comment: Try setting the position based on the image container rather than image size, as image size will differ. i.e  tmpPos = New Point(Picturebox1.Width - textSize.Width - 1, Picturebox1.Height - textSize.Height - 10)

Answer (score 1):

is this problem only occuring in your preview or also in the converted File? Please post the Code how you save the New Image. I think you have Set a sizemode in your picturebox which is the Problem. Try it without the sizemode.

Answer (score 0):

Will be better to see more your code, but, as i understand by TextRenderer class it is System.Windows.Forms. Just do not use Graphics, created from control (i suppose it is pictureBox with sizemode:Zoom), use Graphics, created from your image instead.

Here is code (sorry, C#), which loads image from file, draws text starting from the same coordinate and places on puctureBox1. Text always starts from Point(100,100).

```
 OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

    openFileDialog1.Filter = "Image files|*.jpeg;*.png;*.jpg;*.gif;*.bmp";
    if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        try
        {
            Bitmap orig=(Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            //workaround for images with color table, see remarks here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.fromimage(v=vs.110).aspx 
            Bitmap bmp=orig.Clone(new Rectangle(0, 0, orig.Width, orig.Height), System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppPArgb);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
            g.DrawString("hello", new Font(this.Font.FontFamily,30,FontStyle.Bold )  , new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Yellow ), new Point(100, 100));
            this.pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
            orig.Dispose();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Something goes wrong: " + ex.Message+ "\\n"+ ex.StackTrace );
        }
    }
```